# Colorear las lineas de este triángulo de Sierpinsky

Tags: python

¿cómo hago para ponerle color a las lineas que hace este código?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
k=int(input("Ingrese el valor: "))
X1=200
Y1=100
X2 = 50
Y2 = 300
X3 = 500
Y3 = 200

class Aplicacion():
    def __init__(self):
        self.raiz = Tk()
        self.raiz.title("Dibujos")



        self.cnvLienzo = Canvas(self.raiz, bg = "white", height=400, width=800)
        self.btnLineaH = ttk.Button(self.raiz,
                                text = "Trángulo nivel {}".format(k) ,
                                   command = self.dibujeLineaH)




        self.cnvLienzo.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True,
                          padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btnLineaH.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True,
                          padx=5, pady=5)



        self.raiz.mainloop()

    def dibujeLineaH(self):
        def sier(m,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
            if m == 1 :

                self.cnvLienzo.create_line( x1  ,y1 ,
                                    x2,y2)
                self.cnvLienzo.create_line( x1  ,y1 ,
                                    x3,y3)
                self.cnvLienzo.create_line( x3  ,y3 ,
                                    x2,y2)

            else:
                x4 = (x1 +x2)/2
                y4 = (y1 + y2)/2
                x5 = (x2 + x3)/2
                y5 = (y2 + y3)/2
                x6 = (x3 + x1)/2
                y6 = (y3 + y1)/2

                sier(m-1, x1,y1, x4,y4,x6,y6, )
                sier(m-1, x2,y2, x4,y4,x5,y5,  )
                sier(m-1, x3,y3, x6,y6,x5,y5,  )
        sier(k,X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3 )





def main():
    mi_app = Aplicacion()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende de qué colores quieras asignarle.

Una opción muy simple es dibujar todos los segmentos de curva de Sierpinsky de un mismo color, digamos rojo.

Basta que cambies lo siquiente:

```
    def sier(m,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
        color = "red"
        if m == 1 :
            self.cnvLienzo.create_line( x1  ,y1 ,
                                x2,y2, fill=color)
            self.cnvLienzo.create_line( x1  ,y1 ,
                                x3,y3, fill=color)
            self.cnvLienzo.create_line( x3  ,y3 ,
                                x2,y2, fill=color)
        # El resto igual...
```

El resultado sería:

[image: rojo]

Resultados más interesantes pueden logarse si haces que el color de cada segmento sea diferente, pero aquí sería necesario inventar algún algorimo para generar colores adecuados según el segmento a pintar.

Solo como experimento, podemos hacer que la componente Red del color varíe según el valor de la coordenada `x1`, la componente Green con la coordenada `y1` y la componente Blue con la coordenada `y2`, según unas fórmulas más bien arbitrarias. Después se convierte el valor rgb a una cadena tipo `"#fe2ab7"`, donde cada componente (entre 0 y 255) son dos dígitos hexadecimales.

```
    def sier(m,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
        r,g,b = int(x1/500*255),  int(y1/400*255),  int(x2/800*255)
        color = r*256**2 + g*256 + b
        color = hex(color).replace("0x", "#")
        if m == 1 :
            self.cnvLienzo.create_line( x1  ,y1 ,
                                x2,y2, fill=color)
            self.cnvLienzo.create_line( x1  ,y1 ,
                                x3,y3, fill=color)
            self.cnvLienzo.create_line( x3  ,y3 ,
                                x2,y2, fill=color)
        # El resto igual...
```

Con esta asignación de colores sale así:

[image: Colorines]